# Fire keyup while other keys are still pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check the length of the value of an input and automatically skip to the next one when 3 is reached. I have the code for the skipping, but the way the keyup events are queued are causing me headaches..

Example handler for an input field:

```
    $('input').on('keyup', function (e) {

    var $this = $(this);
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;

    alert(String.fromCharCode(code)+' '+$this.val());

    // Handling of $this.val()==3

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tPyTq/1/

Type three letters before releasing the keys. All of the events already know the final value of the input and therefore my check for the length would fire prematurely and for all three letters.

How can I make the keyup-event fire, while other keys are still pressed?
Please ask, if clarification is needed.

Comment: don't forget that JS is also 'cool': `$(this).val()` == `this.value`

Comment: what's the point of swapping a single line for vanilla javascript if literally of the other lines are jquery?

Answer (score 0):

I get what you mean. This may take a bit of hacking.

try this, though it may not work:

1. Change the event listener to be on `change`

   ```
   $('input').on('change', function(e) {
      //use console rather than alert
      console.log(String.fromCharCode(code)+' '+$this.val());
   });
   ```
2. Then add a separate listener for `keyup`, which fires a change event

   ```
   $('input').on('keyup', function (e) {
       $(this).trigger('change');
   });
   ```